# Mass Redirect Subdomains to Subfolders without Url Change

Tags: apache, .htaccess, subdomain

I'm trying to redirect sub-domain to sub-folders using htaccess. As i have a script that creates sub-folders based on user request, well i just want to serve this sub-folders (creates in public_html) points to sub-domains.

For example if user types this example.com/test then it goes to test.example.com,

Or even if user types test.example.com then it also goes to test.example.com

I have checked many examples in stackoverflow, but not getting the solution that keeps the url to test.example.com on redirection. So how can we hide the redirection

Here is the code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.example\.com
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/%1/$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

The current code redirects test.example.com to example.com/test which is beating the purpose as i have to hide the sub-folder path in browser (domain.com/test).

Thanks

Comment: is there only one folder/subdomain? how many subdomains are there?

Comment: I got your point, its not for specific folder or specific subdomain. I want to point this for all the subfolders that are in my public html.
let say x,y,z... etc. basically i need a universal rewrite rule that will applicable on all.

Comment: Well the above code is working fine.  At the moment :
test.domain.com >> domain.com/test

And i want to hide the redirection (domain.com/test). 

So user wont get to know the data is store in some subfolder.